# Make a file picking process as automated as possible

Tags: javascript, html

I have a php program that needs a file that exists in a certain server.
I wanted to make the picking of that remote file as automated as possible.
I have this input tag:

```
<input name="infoFile" >
```

Now I'd like to have the following process as automatic as possible (except the submitting):

- Open the file picker.
- Fill the url into the picking space.

And then the user presses the open and the submit button.
I want to use no security exploits.

Why not making this is the server?
This is an alternate to use when:

- allow_url_fopen is set to false
- curl is disabled.

Comment: The `input` tag is for picking local files only, and subject to massive restrictions. What do you mean by "exists in a certain server" exactly - how, through what protocol, is the target file accessible?

Comment: if you write a url in the file picker, at least, windows will download the file to a temp folder and allow it to be uploaded to the server

Comment: I think that won't work for a file input, though. Why not provide a normal text field, have the user paste the URL there, and fetch it from server side?

Comment: how can I do it if allow_url_fopen is set to false and curl is disabled? Also, the server already knows the corresponding url. It just can't access it using the means it has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a good way to use the user's machine to fetch the file. The Same Origin Policy will prevent any Ajax access to the remote file, and pre-filling the file input is impossible due to security.

I think the best you can do is provide the download link for the user to click on. Alternatively, get `allow_url_fopen` or `curl` enabled - if at all possible.

Also alternatively, a Flash program should be able to fetch the remote file, and upload straight away. I'm not aware of a ready-made script for that, so it would have to be custom built.

Comment: I have no flash knowlage. Actaully, I'm against flash. It's too inefficient, too CPU comsuming. I think, if no alternative exists, I should keep the user instructions for use this functionality.